# Can I assume that the dimension of a vector space is always non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove that if $V$ is finite-dimensional and $U_1,...,U_m$ are subspaces of $V$, then $\dim(U_1+...+U_m)\le \dim U_1+...+\dim U_m$ through induction.

For $m=1$, the inequality is trivial because $\dim U_1 = \dim U_1$. I assume that the inequality holds for $m=k$. This means that $\dim(U_1+...+U_k)\le \dim U_1+...+\dim U_k$. I want to prove that the inequality holds for $m=k+1$ if it is assumed to hold when $m=k$.

$\quad\dim(U_1+...+U_{k+1})$ 
$\\ = \dim((U_1+...+U_k)+U_{k+1})$ 
$\\ = \dim(U_1+...+U_k)+\dim U_{k+1} -\dim((U_1+...+U_k)\bigcap U_{k+1})$ $\\\le \dim U_1+...+\dim U_k + \dim U_{k+1} -\dim((U_1+...+U_k)\bigcap U_{k+1})$

$\therefore \dim(U_1+...+U_{k+1})\le \dim U_1+...+\dim U_k + \dim U_{k+1} -\dim((U_1+...+U_k)\bigcap U_{k+1})$

If I can assume that $-\dim((U_1+...+U_k)\bigcap U_{k+1})$ is non-positive since intuitively, dimensions of vector spaces are non-negative, the inequality is satisfied. I need to know if there is a proof that for "ordinary" vector spaces, the dimensions are non-negative. Of course, there are undoubtedly better ways to prove this and my proof may be wrong since I'm assuming things but I wanted to see if there was any chance this proof would be legit.

Comment: Note: There is such a thing as a $0$-dimensional space. That should be your base case.

Answer (score 5):

The dimension of a vector space whatever it is is the cardinality of its basis. Cardinalities can't be negative

Comment: I see. So my proof would be sufficient right?

Comment: yes and actually i don't think there is another way to do it

Comment: there might be but that's how i prove it